# How to send a message and an embed when streamer is live? | Error | Discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, twitch

I have written the code to check if Twitch streamer is life, if so send a message, but i can't find a way to check if life notification(message and embed) is already send. So I tried different things of checking embed title: `if discord.Embed(title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}") == embed:` and `if discord.Embed(title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}"):`. But in the first case bot is spamming, in the second case bot doesn't activate else statement(which i need to send notification), so i am getting spammed or instead bot doesn't send anything at all. Please help me: I need balance, when streamer is live send ONE notification and then `break`(then check only if statement which must prevent bot from spamming. Here is the CODE. I recommend you taking a look between line 74 and 119. Especially line 99 with if statement.

```
import os
import json
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.utils import get
from server import ping
from Time import mytimemy

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

TOKEN = os.getenv('token')

# Authentication with Twitch API.
client_id = os.getenv('client_id')
client_secret = os.getenv('Dweller_token')
body = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    "grant_type": 'client_credentials'
}
r = requests.post('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token', body)
keys = r.json()
headers = {
    'Client-ID': client_id,
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keys['access_token']
}

'''user_info = twitch.get_users(logins=['turb4ik'])
user_id = user_info['data'][0]['id']
print(user_info)'''

# Returns true if online, false if not.
def checkuser(streamer_name):
    stream = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + streamer_name, headers=headers)
    stream_data = stream.json()

    if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
        return True, stream_data
    else:
        return False, stream_data


# Executes when bot is started
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Defines a loop that will run every 10 seconds (checks for live users every 10 seconds).
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def live_notifs_loop():
        # username = stream_data['data'][0]['user_name']
        # stream_title = stream_data['data'][0]['title']
        # game_being_played = stream_data['data'][0]['game_name']

        # Opens and reads the json file
        with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
            streamers = json.loads(file.read())
        # Makes sure the json isn't empty before continuing.
        if streamers is not None:
            # Gets the guild, 'twitch streams' channel, and streaming role.
            guild = bot.get_guild(690995360411156531)
            channel = bot.get_channel(785523710362124298)
            role = get(guild.roles, id=835581408272580649)
            # Loops through the json and gets the key,value which in this case is the user_id and twitch_name of
            # every item in the json.
            for user_id, twitch_name in streamers.items():
                print("Checking" + " " + str(twitch_name) + " Current time: " + str(mytimemy()))
                # Takes the given twitch_name and checks it using the checkuser function to see if they're live.
                # Returns either true or false.
                status, stream_data = checkuser(twitch_name)
                # Gets the user using the collected user_id in the json
                user = bot.get_user(int(user_id))
                # Makes sure they're live
                if status is True:
                    # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                  async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                      twitch_embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}",
                                color=0xac1efb,
                                url=f'\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}'
                          )
                      twitch_embed.add_field(
                            name = '**Game**',
                            value = stream_data['data'][0]['game_name'], 
                            inline = True
                          )
                      twitch_embed.add_field(
                            name = '**Viewers**',
                            value = stream_data['data'][0]['viewer_count'], 
                            inline = True
                          )
                      twitch_embed.set_author(
                              name = str(twitch_name),
                              icon_url = stream_data['data'][0]['thumbnail_url']
                                                          )
                      twitch_embed.set_image(url = f'https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}')
                      embeds = message.embeds
                      for embed in embeds:
                        if discord.Embed(title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}") == embed:
                          try:
                              embed_title = twitch_embed.title
                              embed_description = twitch_embed.description
                          except Exception as e:
                              break
                          print(f"Already sent for {user.name} at {mytimemy()}!") #just sending the time and name
                          break

                        else:
                            # Gets all the members in your guild.
                          async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                              # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and
                              # they're live, give them the streaming role.
                              if member.id == int(user_id):
                                  await member.add_roles(role)
                          # Sends the live notification to the 'twitch streams' channel then breaks the loop.
                          await channel.send(
                              content = f"Hey @everyone! {user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! Go check it out: https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}", embed=twitch_embed)
                          print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                          break
                # If they aren't live do this:
                else:
                    # Gets all the members in your guild.
                    async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                        # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and they're not
                        # live, remove the streaming role.
                        if member.id == int(user_id):
                            await member.remove_roles(role)
                    # Checks to see if the live notification was sent.
                    async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                        try:
                            embed_title = message.embeds[0].title
                            embed_description = message.embeds[0].description
                        except Exception as e:
                            break
                        # If it was, delete it.
                        if str(user.name) in embed_title and "is now streaming" in embed_title:
                            print(f"{user} stopped streaming. Removing the notification.")
                            await message.delete()
    # Start your loop.
    live_notifs_loop.start()


# Command to add Twitch usernames to the json.
@bot.command(name='addtwitch', help='Adds your Twitch to the live notifs.', pass_context=True)
async def add_twitch(ctx, twitch_name):
    # Opens and reads the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'r') as file:
        streamers = json.loads(file.read())

    # Gets the users id that called the command.
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    # Assigns their given twitch_name to their discord id and adds it to the streamers.json.
    streamers[user_id] = twitch_name

    # Adds the changes we made to the json file.
    with open('streamers.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(streamers))
    # Tells the user it worked.
    await ctx.send(f"Added {twitch_name} for {ctx.author} to the notifications list.")

ping()

print('Server Running')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

It is very hard to explain and understand, but please help me. I need to check embed content while someone is streaming, so the embed and message are send one time per stream and NO spamming. And when stream goes off forget that embed content, so the embed can be send next time too. If u don't understand something, please ask. My discord just in case: Dweller_Igor#3291. Please someone EDIT the question, if it helps you better understand it.

MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE (embed, if-statement and else-statement):

```
if status is True:
                    # Checks to see if the live message has already been sent.
                  async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
                      twitch_embed = discord.Embed(
                                title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}",
                                color=0xac1efb,
                                url=f'\nhttps://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}'
                          )
                      twitch_embed.add_field(
                            name = '**Game**',
                            value = stream_data['data'][0]['game_name'], 
                            inline = True
                          )
                      twitch_embed.add_field(
                            name = '**Viewers**',
                            value = stream_data['data'][0]['viewer_count'], 
                            inline = True
                          )
                      twitch_embed.set_author(
                              name = str(twitch_name),
                              icon_url = stream_data['data'][0]['thumbnail_url']
                                                          )
                      twitch_embed.set_image(url = f'https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}')
                      embeds = message.embeds
                      for embed in embeds:
                        if discord.Embed(title=f":red_circle: **LIVE**\n{user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! \n \n {stream_data['data'][0]['title']}") == embed:
                          try:
                              embed_title = twitch_embed.title
                              embed_description = twitch_embed.description
                          except Exception as e:
                              break
                          print(f"Already sent for {user.name} at {mytimemy()}!") #just sending the time and name
                          break

                        else:
                            # Gets all the members in your guild.
                          async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
                              # If one of the id's of the members in your guild matches the one from the json and
                              # they're live, give them the streaming role.
                              if member.id == int(user_id):
                                  await member.add_roles(role)
                          # Sends the live notification to the 'twitch streams' channel then breaks the loop.
                          await channel.send(
                              content = f"Hey @everyone! {user.name} is now streaming on Twitch! Go check it out: https://www.twitch.tv/{twitch_name}", embed=twitch_embed)
                          print(f"{user} started streaming. Sending a notification.")
                          break
```

Comment: You're supposed to add a [***minimal*** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) not your whole project.

Comment: oh, sorry. i thought everything is an issue. i will edit, sorry

Comment: Try adding some debugging print statements. It seems a simple logic error to me, though with that much code it's not really possible to narrow it down

Comment: i did that. but it depends: if it spams it prints only else-statement, if it doesn't send anything at all it prints if-statement

Comment: should i add `print` in every statement? i did that, but i need to get embed content. when embed is not yet send bot sends an embed and then bot check the content of the embed, if content is true then bot doesn't send anything at all. i know. but if check the title and title is true then i dont get any notification at all, but the embed is not yet send. so? maybe im just dumb or whatever

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński sorry, maybe is there a way of sending a message in else-statement and then immediately get the id of the message and save that message id in variable and put that variable in if-statement. so if `message.id == variable` then start if-statement and prevent bot from spamming. is that possible? can I do that using `channel.history()` and how? please help

Comment: I guess, `message = await channel.send()`, and the ID would be `message.id`

Comment: For example: `idmessage = await channel.send()` How do I get `idmessage` id? `message.get(idmessage.id)` ? @ŁukaszKwieciński sorry for bothering you

Comment: The message ID is simply `idmessage.id`

Comment: nah, still spamming and it also gives me channel info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await ctx.send(content = "some message", embed = embed)
```

> It was a very stupid question at the time, and it still is to this day